# Is there any per app device-id on ios and android?

Tags: android, ios

We need a per-app-per-device unique id to identify a user across app reinstall.

Both `IDFV` on iOS and `App Set Id` on Android may change upon app reinstall or OS upgrade.

Is there something like the following `app_device_id`?

```
hidden_device_id # generated upon phone factory reset/setup

app_device_id = sha256([hidden_device_id,app_id]) # computed by the OS so no security/privacy issue
```

Comment: Please read: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids Any consistent id is considered a PII issue. After reading all of the options in the link, you should explain why those alternates aren't adequate.

Comment: on iOS you can store your own uuid in the keychain.  This will be maintained across re-installs (Although Apple tried to change this in the past and may do so again) but not device erase.  You can look at Apple's device check framework if you want to block a specific device.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, Just cant understand why an intented maintance of state across resintall is an issue.

Comment: @somebody4 You can use google ads library for per-app-per-device unique id to identify a user

Comment: @somebody4 Or just use a login/password and sync data with your servers.

Comment: @somebody4 Because devices don't stay with one owner.  Let's say I download your app.  Then in a year, I get a new device and sell or give away this one.  I do not want you to remember my device id and give the new owner access to all my account data.  That's a horrible security breech.  And that's why you don't do it.  If you want to maintain data across sessions like that, you use a username and password for an account on your server.  That also allows me to log back in when I install your app on my new device, something a device id scheme doesn't allow.

Comment: @GabeSechan It wont happen if the OS reset a hidden device id upon factory reset.

Comment: @MorrisonChang We want to minimise the steps before users can start using the app.

Comment: @somebody4 You haven't stated your use case for persistence. Please go through the link in my first comment and edit your post to include your use case and why any recommendation in that document doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: @MorrisonChang We want to create temp account for new user, which also recieve some free gift. So being able to track the account even after app reinstall would be great.

Comment: @somebody4 You're assuming it gets reset between users.  While that's a best practice, it's hardly universal.  Which is why such IDs no longer exist.